Streamming file with @Command() in Nestjs
I'm using **@Command()** to **stream files** into the **gg cloud**. If you call the API to stream files, it works fine; the cloud contains files. But if I run a command, after the command is done, there is no file in the cloud. I suspect that the command process is killed before the stream process is done, so files do not appear in the cloud. By the way, If I use **set-timeout** to wait about 5 seconds instead of **await** then everything's ok, but I dont know how long have to wait. Here is my command code:
@Command({})
async run(_input: string[], _options: Record<string, string> = {}): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const testPromise = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.service.uploadStream(_input);
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('===== Done =====');
        }, 5000);
      });
      await testPromise();
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
    } finally {
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }

Here's my stream function:
async uploadStream(
    stream: Transform,
    filePath: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const file = this.getFile(filePath);

      stream.pipe(file.createWriteStream());
      stream.on('error', (error) => reject(error));
      stream.on('finish', async () => {
        return resolve();
      });
      stream.end();
    });
  }

I dont want to use set-timeout anymore.
